# Ignore paramter if field is null: Invalid token (

Tags: sql, db2, case, where-clause, ibm-midrange

I have a parameter in the where clause of my query I am trying to ignore if a field is blank.  Receiving an "invalid token (" error.

```
WHERE ....  
AND    
CASE WHEN trim (cltfst) || ' ' || (cltlst) is null THEN ''
    ELSE (('LWSI:first_status')='(All)' or TRIM (status) in ('LWSI:status_list'))
    END = 'TEST'
```

Says:  "Invalid token (, Valid tokens (" if that makes any sense!

Comment: What are you trying to do with `ELSE (('LWSI:first_status')='(All)' or TRIM (status) in ('LWSI:status_list'))`? What value are you trying to return there? It doesn't look like that `CASE` could ever return 'TEST'.

Comment: The "else" line is my parameter.  I am simply inserting the paramter selected by the user there.  It works when I use it in a "regular" where clause.  And you are right, I don't want "Test" returned at all.  I am just playing with syntax trying to get something to work.

Comment: That's probably your problem, it doesn't belong in the `ELSE` clause of the `CASE`. The ELSE clause of the CASE must return a value. It cannot be a logical expression.

Comment: So how to accomplish this?

Comment: Just use an OR in the WHERE clause of the select. Give us more information, and I can give you a better answer.

Comment: All I want to do is IGNORE the status parameter when cltfst/cltlst is null.

Comment: See my answer. I believe you are thinking about it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two conditions for a query, lets call them condition_a and condition_b, and if condition_a is true, then you don't care what condition_b is (you ignore it). You can handle that in your WHERE clause with an OR like this:

```
select ...
from ...
where condition_a or condition_b
```

To ignore a logical condition if a field (field1) is blank, this would look like

```
select ...
from ...
where (field1 = '' or condition_a)
  and condition_x
```

In this case if field1 = blank, the condition is true no matter what condition_a is. condition_x will still have to be evaluated, but condition_a is effectively ignored if field1 is blank. But, if field1 is not blank, then condition_a must be true for the record to be selected. Once again, condition_x must be evaluated and also be true.

---

More specifically to your situation:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
  and (trim (cltfst) || ' ' || (cltlst) is null or
        (('LWSI:first_status')='(All)' or TRIM (status) in ('LWSI:status_list')))
```

Not real sure what all your short hand means here, but it is ignored if `trim (cltfst) || ' ' || (cltlst) is null`.

Comment: Thank you Sir!  Sometimes a 2nd set of eyes is very helpful!